# How to bind Checked event for radio button in WPF?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, eventtrigger

I am using the following markup in WPF:

```
    <StackPanel.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="RadioButton.Checked" SourceName="xmlRadioButton">
            <EventTrigger.Actions>
                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource ShowXmlPanel}"/>
            </EventTrigger.Actions>
        </EventTrigger>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="RadioButton.Checked" SourceName="adiRadioButton">
            <EventTrigger.Actions>
                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource ShowAdiPanel}"/>
            </EventTrigger.Actions>
        </EventTrigger>
    </StackPanel.Triggers>
```

Though this works fine when I run the code, I get the following error in the designer window of VS 2008:

> Value 'RadioButton.Checked' cannot be
>   assigned to property 'RoutedEvent'.
>   Invalid event name.

Any idea why, and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`RadioButton` is a `ToggleButton`. The designer does support the attached `ToggleButton` properties, but not the `RadioButton` ones (except in a `RadioButton` tag of course).

You need to use the class name that defines the property/event for the designer to accept it (thought there is no difference at runtime, since `RadioButton` IS a `ToggleButton` as I said, but the designer is not a real compiler).

So in your case, use `<EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ToggleButton.Checked ..."` ;-)